# Does the Craft Anything Feat mean you do not need a formula?

Tags: feats, crafting, pathfinder-2e

In Pathfinder 2e we have the Feat called [Craft Anything](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=773).  Which states, in part, that

> As long as you have the appropriate Crafting skill feat (such as Magical Crafting for magic items) and meet the item’s level and proficiency requirement, you ignore just about any other requirement, such as being of a specific ancestry or providing spells. The only exceptions are requirements that add to the item’s cost, castings of spells that themselves have a cost, and requirements of special items such as the philosopher’s stone that have exclusive means of access and Crafting. The GM decides whether you can ignore a requirement.

The description of the [Crafting Skill](https://2e.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ID=4) under the subheading *Crafting Trained Actions* states, in part, that

> To Craft an item, you must meet the following requirements:
>
> ..
>
> - You have the formula for the item
>
> ..

[Craft Anything](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=773) is a legendary feat, but does it override the need for a formula?  Is the formula a

> requirement[s] that add to the item’s cost

Answer (score 3):

This is covered by the last sentence of the feat's text, which says:

> The GM decides whether you can ignore a requirement.

Although the rest of the text identifies several cases that either explicitly are or are not covered by the Craft Anything feat's benefits, all other cases are subject to your GM's decision. Since having a formula is a requirement for crafting, but isn't explicitly described, then your GM will decide whether you can ignore it or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is accurate. I feel like this is an oversight. I would consider it as adding to the cost, personally but would totally understand someone else saying "Craft Anything" means *Anything* and allowing it due to its Legendary status

Comment: @Ifusaso It's all GM interpretation, but I understand the word "cost" to be like a financial cost. The formula doesn't add to the cost, it just tells you what the cost is. I'm not sure how I would decide as a GM. Maybe someone else will chip in with that experience.

Comment: Well the formulae have their own cost for scribing them (not dissimilar to spells) that is not insignificant for appropriately leveled items. That, to me, shows an *intended* access cost that I don't know if I would want to ignore. (But I totally get the other side as well)